# Why does Windows always start?

Tags: windows, batch-file, operating-system, dos, startup

Everyone who owns a PC with a Windows OS knows that Windows starts on boot, always. I want to know how exactly they put together the .bat(or maybe .exe) files to automatically start a program on boot. How can I replicate this with DOS batch files to start a program on boot, without any OS installed (other than the fact that it a DOS based system)?

Comment: The keyword you want to search for is "boot loader".

Comment: You should probably go to school and take a class. Operating System design was a required class back in my day and you learned how the computers bios passed off control to the operating system.

Comment: DOS is an operating system just like Windows. If you have no OS installed at all, you won't be able to start a batch file.

Comment: maybe [this](http://bootdisk.net) is a good start. Also googling for `windows boot process` (or `dos boot process`) gives you tons of Information.

Answer (score 1):

Autoexec.bat is started every time a DOS-based system starts.

Place a line in your autoexec.bat to start your batch file :

```
CALL C:\file.bat
```

Comment: autoexec.bat will only run after Windows itself boots up

Comment: He said he wanted to start it from a DOS based system without Windows installed. But indeed, his question is unclear and he might look for a boot loader.

Comment: True. There may be a confusion between BIOS, DOS, OS (and others).

Answer (score 1):

Computers, not operating systems, start OSs. For most of history there is a partition marked as boot. So it loads the hard drive code, that looks for a boot record on the boot partition. Loads it and it loads windows. So boot hard drive and boot partition on that hard drive.

Floppies skip the first step. The floppy is assumed to have the boot code.

Don't get confused by Windows  terminology. It refers to different things. Windows (or any other OS) boots from system partition and loads files (c:\windows\system32, c:\boot, and c:) from the boot partition.

All this has been upgraded to new technologies.